# How to perform indexing on a COMSOL eigenfrequency solution?

Tags: indexing, eigenvalue, comsol

Applying an eigenfrequency study on a solid mechanics problem in COMSOL 6.1, the eigenfrequencies are returned in a table format using `solid.freq`. However, I want to index individual eigenfrequencies, in order to perform computations. Example:

`solid.freq(1) + solid.freq(2)`.

However, this indexing method does not work. I tried `withsol('sol1, solid.freq, setind(Omega, 1))` but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter required is lambda, and the following works:
`withsol('sol1', freq, setind('lambda', 1))`.

The value of 1 returns the first eigenfrequency.